# Accessing first index within a multidimensional array and comparing it wit a number

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Please how do I access all the first indexes of this multi dimensional array.

```
$cars = array (
  array(1,2,3),
  array(4,5,6),
  array(7,8,9),
  array(10,11,12),
);
```

as
`(1,4,7,10)`

and compare the results with a different value as `1` to check if value `1` exists in the array results  `(1,4,7,10)`

where `(1,4,7,10)`    is the first indexes of the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return `true` if 1 exists in the first column of `$cars` array:

```
in_array(1, array_column($cars, 0))
```